# Dummy for multivariate time series regression (intercept and slope effect)

Tags: time-series, self-study, categorical-data

I am trying to understand if it is possible to use dummy observations in time series analysis, to split the effect of two or more groups in the model.

Assume that we have n observations for 4 variables and there are two groups A and B. In the first group there are the first two variables and in B the last two.

Is there any way possibile to create a dataset that consider the slope and intercept effect of the two groups?

Thank you.

Comment: Is this a panel or time series?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the independent slope and intercept of each group just set the data values in the other group to zero.

I.e., given "grouped" variables $A = (a_1, a_2), B=(b_1, b_2)$ your general linear regression is of the form

$$\vec{y} = \alpha + (\beta_1 \vec{a_1} + \beta_2 \vec{a_2}) + (\beta_3 \vec{b_1} + \beta_4 \vec{b_2}) + \vec{\epsilon}$$

Hold $\beta_1 = \beta_2 = 0$ and solve the equations and the slope and intercept you get are attributable to the variables *B* independently.  Then do the same for group *B* values to get the independent slope and intercept of variables *A*.

Note, however, that you may get more information on the explanatory power of each independent variable by looking at their associated $R^2$, t-stat, and/or the correlation matrix.